# The... rising numbers of those out of work are adding greatly to the government's problems

Tags: adjectives, gerunds

Which option fits best for the followings sentence:

> The.........rising numbers  of those out of work are adding greatly to the
>    government's problems.
>
> 1. High
> 2. Hard
> 3. Steeply
> 4. Promptly

---

This question also prompted another related question in my mind about a general grammar guides.

As we know, the word *rising* is an adjective. I'd like to ask if it is grammatically correct to use another adjective before a gerund + noun phrase.

> 1. Rapid rising prices caused chaos.
> 2. Rapid developing countries..

Comment: I don't think there is any rule regarding this. For instance, we say: *It was wonderful seeing you again yesterday* and *It is wonderful to see you again.* Both, in my opinion, are correct.

Comment: You can use an adjective if it also modifies the noun, but you must use an adverb if you are modifying the gerund. I would use "rapidly" in each of the last two examples. The prices aren't rapid; they are rising rapidly. The countries aren't rapid; they are developing rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes verbs can turn into adjectives by adding *-ing*. These are called **[participles](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/8/adjectives-and-verbs/)**. In this example, *rising* is a type of adjective called a **participle**.

**Adjectives** modify nouns (see [these](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/1/what-are-adjectives/) [links](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40376/which-adjectives-can-describe-verbs)). **Adverbs** modify verbs, adjectives, and other adverbs (see [this](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/6/adverbs-modify-verbs-adjectives-and-other-adverbs/)). *High* and *hard* are adjectives, so they cannot modify the participle (adjective) *rising*.

From the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/promptly), *promptly* has these definitions:

1. With little or no delay; immediately
2. At exactly a specified time; punctually

The context of the sentence suggests that the problem is worsening *over time*, and the sentence does not refer to a specific time or instance. So, *promptly* does not fit the sentence.

The only remaining choice is *steeply*. Steeply is an adverb, and it can be applied to an ongoing situation.

> The **steeply** rising numbers of those out of work are adding greatly
>   to the government's problems.

In the second example, *rapid* is an adjective, so it cannot modify *rising* or *developing*. Adding *-ly* turns it into an adverb, and adverbs can modify adjectives. So, ***rapidly*** can modify *rising* or *developing*. Both of these are correct:

> Rapid**ly** rising prices caused chaos.
>
> Rapid**ly** developing countries...